# Convergence and numerical accuracy

Tags: sequences-and-series, rate-of-convergence

I know that a sequence of real numbers $\{x_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$ converges to a limit $L$ which is an irrational number that is only known as  the limit of the above sequence (ie there is no other way to have access to an approximate value of $L$). Is there a way to find after which number of terms $n$ in the above sequence, a given number of digits of $L$ are exact?

As an example, the sequence is $x_n=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i^2}$ but my question is general. I should also mention that relying on an algorithm to answer the question is acceptable. Is there a systematic way to check that the $k$ first numerically found digits are exact?

Comment: I guess that depends on the rate of convergence of the sequence. Consider, for example, sequences $a_n = 1/n$ and $b_n = 1/n^2$. Both converge to zero, but what you are asking for will be different for each one. Do you have a particular sequence in mind?

Comment: @gt6989b yes, sorry I forgot to mention that I explicitly know the sequence. Here, it would be $x_n=\sum_{i=1}^n 1/i^2$ but my question is general. I should also mention that relying on an algorithm to answer the question is acceptable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, and there are three different problems that stop it.

One is that there are breakpoints where the number changes from $2.9999$ to $3.0000$ or something like that.  A tiny change in the sum can change a lot of digits.  We can eliminate this one by asking that we know the sum better than $\pm 5\cdot 10^{-k}$ instead of asking for $k$ accurate digits.

The second is that there might be large numbers far out in the sum.  The sequence $x_n$ may look well behaved, but unknown to you $x_{10^{1000}}=1,000,000$.  You can't get any decimals right until you add more terms than that.

The third is that some nicely specified series converge *very* slowly.  We know that $\sum \frac 1n$ diverges like $\log n$.  Less well known is that $\sum \frac 1{n \log n}$ diverges like $\log(\log(n))$.  On the other hand, $\sum \frac 1{n(\log n)^2}$ converges, but very slowly.  $\sum \frac 1{n\log n (\log(\log n))^2}$ converges more slowly yet.

Responding to your comment that you have the specific series $x_n=\sum_{i=1}^n 1/i^2$ we can give an answer.  You can just look at the partial sum and see it does not have a string of $9$s at the end.  We know there are not stray terms that are very large because you have a nice formula.  We can improve the convergence by seeing it as a Riemann sum for the integral $\int_1^\infty \frac 1{x^2}dx=1$ and work on the error term.  The error term will be of order $\frac 1{x^3}$ so is more manageable.  When the series has a nice formula you can often bound the truncation error to give a number of terms to get a number of decimals.  There is not a general procedure.

Comment: Thank you. But then, for the people computing the digits of $\pi$ (about trillions of them at the moment I believe), how do they know that they are correct?

Comment: For a specific calculation there may be an error bound.  The $\pi$ calculations do have this, so they know how many terms are required.  For the first one, you can just look and see there is not a series of $9$s.  Your question was too general to count on having an error bound.